# Show different sidebar image for different categories

Tags: magento-1.9, php, category, phtml, static-block

I have 5 root categories and I want different left sidebar image for each category. I'm using Porto theme in which I can fix a static block in my left sidebar but then it cannot change the image according to category. Example: poster of tshirts in Fashion category and poster of headphone in Electronics category. I'm using magento 1.9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This made it work, first I created a static block "activity_tracker_poster" then in activity tracker's category >> Custom design >> Custom Layout Update, I wrote this.

```
<reference name="left"> 
<block type="cms/block" name="left_block" before=' '>
<action method="setBlockId"><block_id>activity_tracker_poster</block_id></action>
</block>
</reference>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well static blocks are... static. 
You have two options here.
1. Create a widget

2. Add a phtml file in your template that does what you want.

For (2), Insert sth like this in your static block

```
{{block type="core/template" template="catalog/category/image.phtml"}}
```

Then create app/design/frontend/[package]/[theme]/template/catalog/category/image.phtml with the following content

```
<?php if($categoryId=Mage::registry('current_category')):?>
    <?php /*Add your image logic here. For example*/?>
    <?php switch ($categoryId) {
    case 11:
        $categoryImage = 'cat11.jpg';
        break;
    case 12:
        $categoryImage = 'cat12.jpg';
        break;
    case 13:
        $categoryImage = 'cat13.jpg';
        break;
     default:
        $categoryImage = null;
     }?>
     <?php if($categoryImage):?>
        <img src="path/to/image/<?php echo  $categoryImage;?>"/>
     <?php endif;?>
<?php endif;?>
```

The switch is just an example. You can for example get the Category Image from the categories collection